# Gitlab: Issues and Pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have setup a Git project + CI (using Gitlab-runner) on Gitlab v12.3.5. I have a question about issues and pipelines. Let's say I create an issue and assign it to myself. So this create a branch/merge request. Then, I open up the WebIDE to modify some files in an attempt to fix the issue. Now I want to see what if my changes will fix the issue. In order to run the pipeline, is it necessary to commit the changes into the branch or is there some other way?

The scenario I have is that it may take me 20 times to fix the files to make the pipeline 'clean'. In that case, I would have to keep committing on each change to see the results. What is the preferred way to accomplish this? Is it possible to run the pipeline by just staging the changes to see if they work?

I am setting up the **gitlab-ci.yaml** file. Hence it is taking a lot of trials to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a branch and push to that. Only pushed changes will trigger pipeline runs. After you're done, you can squash and merge the branch so that the repo's history will be clean.

Usually though, you won't have to do this because you'll have automated tests set up to check whether your code works. You should also try testing the Linux commands (or whichever commands you're running in your GitLab CI `script`s) locally first. If you're worried about whether your `.gitlab-ci.yml` syntax is correct, you can navigate to the file in your repository and check there (there's a button at the top which lints it).